# How to setup TOR wi-fi hotspot on Windows?

Tags: configuration, windows, network-configuration

Windows PC is connected to internet via ethernet and shares connection via wi-fi hotspot. All traffic shared by hotspot should be routed through Tor.
This is needed to enable connection to Tor network from device which has no Tor apps (Blackberry Playbook tablet).

Comment: Could you expand your question a bit? It's not clear what you're trying to do, what you want to achieve etc. This helps to give you a better answer.

Comment: @JensKubieziel OK, I've updated it to be more clear

Comment: Do you want to do this for circumvention or anonymity? Due to [protocol](http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/536/what-is-browser-fingerprinting-what-is-linkability) level [leaks](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorifyHOWTO#Protocolleaks) (transparent) [torification](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorifyHOWTO#Terminology) of arbitrary devices and applications might get your a Tor IP, but not be anonymous.

Comment: @adrelanos I want this only for circumvention

Answer (score 3):

You can make the SOCKS proxy (which is what applications use to send traffic through Tor) useable by the local network.

However,

- I don't know whether you can easily configure the tablet to use the proxy.
- The applications on the tablet can selectively disregard the proxy settings.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [tutorial](http://learn.adafruit.com/onion-pi/overview) how to use Raspberry Pi to make your own torified Wi-Fi.