# Create a wifi hotspot by a laptop which pass all traffic through Tor (Windows)

Tags: configuration, windows, network-configuration

I know the product Anonabox which turns a normal connection into wireless Tor traffic. Because the process of creating a wifi access point is relatively easy, I'm wondering is there a way I could route all traffics of the wifi access point through Tor network. I'm on Windows, so tutorials in Windows is more preferable.
Thank you so much. Have a nice day.

Comment: thought about [Connectify](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.connectify.me%2F&ei=DBb1VKDCAtPv8gXyuoEY&usg=AFQjCNES_BbBeA5kq5a61z1ufbz6bmZ7BQ&sig2=9Cmpn_fm1hFpR3Yqrp1CMw&bvm=bv.87269000,d.dGc)????

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to setup TOR wi-fi hotspot on Windows?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/706/how-to-setup-tor-wi-fi-hotspot-on-windows)

Answer (score 2):

Use Virtualbox with USB Wi-Fi dongle. Your host(Windows) will go to the Internet directly, and the Linux VM will be routed through it(NAT or bridge) - and USB 2.0(not 3.0 !) will be a mapping forwarding of USB dongle to VM and via hostapd you will securely do the trick. It is the simpliest *secure* way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an easy way to run Tor on Windows, the [Tor Browser Bundle](https://torproject.org) is the easiest way. If you install it on every Windows machine, practically all traffic going to pass in the wireless access point will go through the Tor network. Smartphone have their own apps that allow them to use Tor.

If that's not what you need, and you are seeking a software-based solution to configure your access point to use Tor, then that is harder to carry out, and there is no way to do it from Windows. You'll have to either use a pre-configured router with Tor pre-installed such as Anonabox, or set up a Linux machine with wireless network card as access point, configure it as a router, and install Tor on it so it can connect all your wireless devices through Tor. This will require a certain level of knowledge in Linux administration & networking.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use **Tortilla** **adapter** by the and tor community. New adapter will be installed along side. Two methods are available

1. Executable
2. Manually create the tortilla bundle adapter with the help of solution.

You can follow build instruction from this git.
https://github.com/CrowdStrike/Tortilla