# Does whonix traffic non browser requests through tor?

Tags: whonix, tor-network

I understand that using the built in browser within whonix is the best way to utilize its privacy and security benefits. However with network scripts for example that make custom requests, do they also have the same privacy measures? I am assuming that all traffic not only browser is also channeled through tor for the privacy inside whonix but I could not really find any clear answers online.

Answer (score 1):

Quote [Whonix Homepage](https://www.whonix.org/):

> The Everything Tor OS

> [All internet traffic is routed](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/About#Security_by_Isolation) through the [Tor anonymity network](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Why_does_Whonix_use_Tor). No exceptions. Whonix is the "All Tor Operating System".

It is better to use Tor Browser even inside Whonix due to its browser fingerprinting defenses. [Quote Whonix wiki page about Tor Browser](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Tor_Browser):

> Hiding your identity is harder than just hiding your
> [IP](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Data_Collection_Techniques#IP). Tor Browser provides protection from [browser fingerprinting](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Data_Collection_Techniques#Browser_Fingerprinting).

See also:
[What is browser fingerprinting? What is linkability?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/536/what-is-browser-fingerprinting-what-is-linkability/541)

Full disclosure: I am a maintainer of Whonix.

Comment: Ok thank you, its just it was never explicitly clearly stated non browser traffic was also routed through tor there is a great emphasis on the browser its self.