# Commenting on blogs

Tags: anonymity

I tried using Tor Browser to comment on blogs (blogspot). The blog I am interested in requires a Gmail login. So I tried to enter through Gmail, but when I tried to comment on the blog, I am unable to find my Gmail login.

What is the best way to use Tor to comment on blogs without letting know my location?

Comment: Is there a way to do it without gmail? If not, then probably not. [Google doesn't treat Tor users very well](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/313/does-google-know-that-i-am-using-tor-browser).